# getting a discord bot to ignore all incoming inputs after detecting spam

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

im working on a discord bot that responds to keywords with some text and an image, as you can imagine this would create a lot of opportunities to use the bot to spam and I would like to create a system in the code that allows the program to stop accepting all inputs once spamming is detected, I managed to create a system to detect the spam using time stamps but so far it does nothing, as I cannot figure out the code for what I need to do.

this is my code so far:

```
import os
import discord
import datetime
import time
from keep_on import keep_on

bot_token = os.environ['TOKEN']

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('{0.user} is online'.format(client))
  print('###########################################')

enabled = True

time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  global enabled
  global time_storage
  sentWord = message.content
  CSentWord = sentWord.upper()
  if message.content == "!start":
    enabled = True
    await message.channel.send("Having Trouble?")
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Having trouble.png'))
  elif message.content == "!stop":
    enabled = False
    await message.channel.send("Ok Ill Stop.")
    await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey will stop.png'))
  elif enabled == True:
    if message.author == client.user:
      return
    if "SORRY" in CSentWord:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      time_delay = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
      time_difference = time_delay - time_storage
      print('time since last stored:',time_storage)
      print('time now:',time_delay)
      print('time difference:',time_difference)
      print('###########################################')
      if time_difference < 5:
        await message.channel.send("You are moving too fast")
        await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Bruh what.png'))
        time.sleep(2)
        return
      await message.channel.send("'We're Very Sorry' - Joey Tribbiani")
      await message.channel.send(file=discord.File('Joey Is Sorry.png'))
      time_storage = int(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp())
 
               
keep_on()
client.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Comment: That's a lot of code... Can you maybe reduce it to the most necessary part or remove some `print` statements?

Comment: i edited my original post to show only what matters

Answer (score 0):

You can add cooldowns to commands using

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
```

For example here the user can use a command once every 10 seconds